# Lulu's Help, Pix! > Teleport

Tags: league-of-legends

As Lulu, you can redirect your passive using Help, Pix! and give it to an ally. Upon doing so, you can use her other ability, Glitterlance, and aim it from yourself and the ally you used Help, Pix! on. What happens if the ally is teleported or moved across the map shortly after your ability? Can you sit in your base and use the abilities in tandem to help, say a Shen, track down a target and slow them with Glitterlance to get an across-the-map Assist (or KS)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, pix has a leash range of 2000. If the supported champion moves out of this range, pix automatically returns to lulu.